# ZIP a folder after creating it with exec results in no folder creation and zipping failing

Tags: php, zip

I have a script that should (in order):

1. create a folder in [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) and place some files in it (done within `exec()` row)
2. zip the folder and its content
3. force the download client-side

I tried step 1 and 3 separately succesfully, but struggling to make step 2 to work.

My script is this one (below the error I am getting):

```
<?php
    $tmpdir = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $outdir = "download";
    $format = "ESRI Shapefile";
    $folderToZip = $tmpdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $outdir;

    $command = "ogr2ogr -f $format $folderToZip WFS:\"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446\" --config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES";

    exec($command);

    // Initialize archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFile = "download.zip";
    $zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folderToZip),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir())
        {
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($folderToZip) + 1);

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }

    // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $zipFile);

    readfile ($zip);
    exit();
?>
```

The error I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\Users\MINORA~1.ONE\AppData\Local\Temp\download,C:\Users\MINORA~1.ONE\AppData\Local\Temp\download): Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
Warning: Unknown: Cannot destroy the zip context in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if the above code is/was completely right but it turns out the error was missing double quotes around `$format` in `$command`, which in turn produced no output and thus `$folderToZip` was not created.

I forgot to put them because I thought a string variable would have included those, but of course it's just the way a string variable is constructed. Either I had to do `$format = "'ESRI Shapefile'";` (instead of `$format = "ESRI Shapefile";`), or (that's what I did), I need to add double quotes explicitely around it in the `$command` like

`$command = "ogr2ogr -f \"$format\" $folderToZip WFS:\"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446\" --config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES";`

, writing `\"$format\"` instead of `$format`.